# Consume Soap Services in AEM

Tags: aem

I want to consume a soap service wsdl using AEM. I am not able to generate stubs in my aem-bundle.I added some dependencies of apache axis that helps me to generate stubs ,but not working.

Comment: Add some code that you have written so far.

Comment: What should i add. I just want to know about dependemcies of doing this?

Comment: You said that you are able to generated stubs, is there a error which is coming after that, you can add error details

Comment: Read Carefully Sandeep.I wrote i am not able to generate stubs.

Comment: Have a look at this blog post: http://www.one-inside.com/consuming-soap-web-service-with-jax-ws-in-cq5-6-1/

Comment: @ShivaniGarg Sorry I got confused by statement "I added some dependencies of apache axis that helps me to generate stubs". You must be getting some error after you added dependencies and doing the build. Thomas also shared a link, that would help.

Comment: @Thomos,the link you have provides not working ,problem is when i use the command wsimport -keep  ... The stubs are not getting created. Pls help in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Apache CXF wsdl2java plugin in your pom to generate the stubs. Example code below:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-cxf-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlRoot>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl</wsdlRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/xxx/xxx.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <!-- This argument(-fe jaxws21), is to ensure that generated stubs 
                                        are JAX-WS 2.1 compliant basically Java 1.6. -->
                                    <extraarg>-fe</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                    <extraarg>com.xxx.xxx.xxx.endpoint.v1</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use wsimport tool to generate JAVA stub**. If you use this tool it doesn't need any 3rd party dependency to deploy in AEM. You can directly integrate your generated stubs to AEM code.

> C:>wsimport -keep -verbose   http://path to your wsdl file?wsdl

Or

> C:>wsimport -keep -verbose   C:\Path\To\your\wsdl\file.wsdl

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/